# Can't find what's wrong in this code

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following script which brings up a dialog on my screen telling me there has been an error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myFunc = function() 
{
    var html='<div class="cs-body">explanation of the error</div>';
    $(html).csDialog();
    return false;
};
</script>
```

I want this dialog to pop-up when my php script returns a "1" value for $error, like this:

```
if ($error==1) {
echo "<script type='javascript'>$(document).ready(myFunc)</script>";
}
```

Even if I leave the if-clause and just echo the script it doensn't do anything. Can somebody tell me what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the JavaScript error console?

Comment: Is the script outputted correctly in the HTML? Make sure it is echoed *after* the inclusion of JQuery.

Comment: try changing script type from 'javascript' to 'text/javascript', also if you're outputing that script within the <body></body> tag you don't need to use $(document).ready , just call myFunc() directly

Comment: @lostsource Does that still work if `myFun` is defined towards the end of the document?

Comment: @lostsource Ok, thanks. Post the `text/javascript` thingy as an answer so Roddeh can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing script type from 'javascript' to 'text/javascript'

that did the trick! thanks lostsource!

Comment: well, i certainly would have accepted it as an aswer if it was posted as an answer and not like a comment, or is there a way to accept a comment as an answer? I'm new here.

Comment: you can see that in my and dinnesh answer we have used `'text/javascript'` so you should have either accept him or my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure, this script fragment is output *after* the inclusion of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you javascript function is defined when running this

```
echo "<script type='javascript'>$(document).ready(myFunc)</script>
```

Include jQuery and your js function in the  tag, just to see if it works.
PS: you should only add js script in the  tag if they are necessary right away, else, added them at the bottom of the  tag. Remember, the loading of js files blocks the loading of any other page resources

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php if ($error==1) {  ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(myFunc)
 </script>";

<?php } ?>
```

Dins